# Trouble closing if statement and while loop in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display some html inside a php "if statement" and during a "While" Loop.
I keep getting unexpected end of file error and I know there are two braces missing but I can't see where to close the while loop properly.
I'm still new to coding so please be gentle... :-)
tried php syntax checker and other similar posts here

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php';?>
    <!-- Navigation -->
<?php include 'includes/navbar.php';?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['post'])) {
    $post = $_GET['post'];
    if (!is_numeric($post)) {
      header("location:index.php");

    }
}
else {
    header('location: index.php');
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$post";
$run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn)) ;
if (mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0 ) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {
    $post_title = $row['title'];
    $post_id = $row['id'];
    $post_author = $row['author'];
    $post_date = $row['postdate'];
    $post_image = $row['image'];
    $post_content = $row['content'];
    $post_tags = $row['tag'];
    $post_status = $row['status'];
  $img_ext = explode(".", $post_image);
    ?>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Blog Post Content Column -->
            <div class="col-lg-8">

                <!--First Post -->
            <hr>
                <p><h2><a href="#"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a></h2></p>
            <p><h3>by <a href="#"><?php echo $post_author; ?></a></h3></p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>Posted on <?php echo $post_date; ?></p>
            <hr>
            <?php if ($img_ext=="mp4"): ?>
                <video controls width="400" height="300">
                <source src="allpostpics/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                Video tag is not supported in this browser.
                </video>
            <?php else : ?>
                <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="allpostpics/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" alt="900 * 300">
                <hr>
                <p><?php echo $post_content; ?></p>
            </div>
            <!-- Blog Sidebar Widgets Column -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php include 'includes/sidebar.php'; ?>
        </div>
  </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
       <?php include 'includes/footer.php';?>
   </div>
     <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<?php if ($img_ext=="mp4"): ?>` doesn't have a corresponding `<?php endif ?>`.

Comment: After you close the `<div class="container">` element. And you don't need the `if` before the `while`, it will simply skip the `while` if there are no rows. Unless you want to display a message in an `else` block of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```php
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
<!-- Navigation -->
<?php include 'includes/navbar.php'; ?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['post'])) {
  $post = $_GET['post'];
  if (!is_numeric($post)) {
    header("location:index.php");

  }
} else {
  header('location: index.php');
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$post";
$run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if (mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {
$post_title = $row['title'];
$post_id = $row['id'];
$post_author = $row['author'];
$post_date = $row['postdate'];
$post_image = $row['image'];
$post_content = $row['content'];
$post_tags = $row['tag'];
$post_status = $row['status'];
$img_ext = explode(".", $post_image);
?>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <!-- Blog Post Content Column -->
        <div class="col-lg-8">

            <!--First Post -->
            <hr>
            <p>
            <h2><a href="#"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a></h2></p>
            <p>
            <h3>by <a href="#"><?php echo $post_author; ?></a></h3></p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>Posted on <?php echo $post_date; ?></p>
            <hr>
          <?php if ($img_ext == "mp4"): ?>
              <video controls width="400" height="300">
                  <source src="allpostpics/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                  Video tag is not supported in this browser.
              </video>
          <?php else : ?>
            <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="allpostpics/<?php echo $post_image; ?>"
                 alt="900 * 300">
          <?php endif; ?>
            <hr>
            <p><?php echo $post_content; ?></p>
        </div>
        <!-- Blog Sidebar Widgets Column -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <?php include 'includes/sidebar.php'; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
    <hr>

    <!-- Footer -->
  <?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
} // End while
} // End if
```

> **Note:** your code was missing `<?php endif; ?>` and two braces at the end.

Comment: Thanks All, the End While and End If at the bottom have gotten rid of my syntax error. I now just need to sort out the dispay of video file vs image file (the start of my troubles) All I get is the alt="900 * 300" displaying so there must be something wrong that part. On another page I have video file embedded no problem (drawn from a mysql DB entry. There might be something wrong with the $img_ext variable.

Comment: @Michael, have updated! (the `endif` was too late and prevented the `$post_content` to be outputted).

Comment: Thanks @Top-Master that fixed some of the problem. The other was that I was trying to "Explode" $img_ext which is an indexed array so I had to make another small change <?php if ($img_ext [1] == "mp4"): ?> (Note the [1] once I added this it now works perfectly.Thanks again.

Comment: How do I give you "Credit" for the help to fix this?

Comment: SO does not yet allow you to upvote, but you should be able to `accept` any answer you like ;-) (simply by clicking the thick sign)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is syntatically more similar to C than to Python or VisualBasic. Indentation means nothing here. Code blocks need to be explicitly open and closed.

There are 2 types to quote the if-else blocks but you did neither of those.

You can either:

### use brackets `if { ... } else { ... }`

Example:

```php
            <?php if ($img_ext=="mp4") { ?>
                <video controls width="400" height="300">
                <source src="allpostpics/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                Video tag is not supported in this browser.
                </video>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="allpostpics/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" alt="900 * 300">
                <hr>
                <p><?php echo $post_content; ?></p>
            <?php } ?>
```

### use colon and keyworkds `if`, `endif`

Example,

```php
            <?php if ($img_ext=="mp4"): ?>
                <video controls width="400" height="300">
                <source src="allpostpics/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                Video tag is not supported in this browser.
                </video>
            <?php else: ?>
                <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="allpostpics/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" alt="900 * 300">
                <hr>
                <p><?php echo $post_content; ?></p>
            <?php endif ?>
```

Just chose which one to go for.

Similarly, you have to close your while-loop with either bracket `}` or `endwhile`, depends of your syntax of choice.

Answer (score 0):

you opened the if statement and forgot to close it also while is not closed closed it after the container gets closed